# How to make a table on more than one page by using the table environment

Tags: tables, tabularx, ltablex

**EDIT** Like some comments below are remarking the `table` environment doesn't allow tables over more than one page. However the solution works fine

I need to make a table over more than one page. The standard approach seems to be to use the `ltablex` environment. However, it doesn't work; also I assume that the `table` environment may also be required for the thesis template I work on (e.g. suppose for the `capture`).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ltablex} 
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Example of an table}
\label{tab:daypack}     
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}cX@{}}  
\toprule
\textbf{Column 1} & \textbf{Column 2} \\[6pt]
\midrule
\endhead
$R$ & 1This is an example sentence \\[6pt]
$R$ & 2As well as the line before \\[6pt]
$A$ & 3Also this is an example \\[6pt]
$R$ & 4This is an example sentence \\[6pt]
$R$ & 5As well as the line before \\[6pt]
$A$ & 6Also this is an example \\[6pt]
$R$ & 7This is an example sentence \\[6pt]
$R$ & 8As well as the line before \\[6pt]
$A$ & 9Also this is an example \\[6pt]
$R$ & 10This is an example sentence \\[6pt]
$R$ & 11As well as the line before \\[6pt]
$A$ & 12Also this is an example \\[6pt]
$R$ & 13This is an example sentence \\[6pt]
$R$ & 14As well as the line before \\[6pt]
$A$ & 15Also this is an example \\[6pt]
$R$ & 16This is an example sentence \\[6pt]
$R$ & 17As well as the line before \\[6pt]
$A$ & 18Also this is an example \\[6pt]
$R$ & 19This is an example sentence \\[6pt]
$R$ & 20As well as the line before \\[6pt]
$A$ & 21Also this is an example \\[6pt]
$R$ & 22This is an example sentence \\[6pt]
$R$ & 23As well as the line before \\[6pt]
$A$ & 24Also this is an example \\[6pt]
$R$ & 25This is an example sentence \\[6pt]
$R$ & 26As well as the line before \\[6pt]
$A$ & 27Also this is an example \\[6pt]
$R$ & 28This is an example sentence \\[6pt]
$R$ & 29As well as the line before \\[6pt]
$A$ & 30Also this is an example \\[6pt]
$R$ & 31This is an example sentence \\[6pt]
$R$ & 32As well as the line before \\[6pt]
$A$ & 33Also this is an example \\[6pt]
$R$ & 34This is an example sentence \\[6pt]
$R$ & 35As well as the line before \\[6pt]
$A$ & 36Also this is an example \\[6pt]
$R$ & 37This is an example sentence \\[6pt]
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}   
\end{table}    

\end{document}
```

Comment: A `table` environment can never be split across pages. The purpose of `ltablex` is exactly not using `table`.

Comment: @egreg Thank you. However, may it be possible to change the code in order to work over more then one page and to add before a empty table? Otherwise could you at least offer a working code without the table environment because it doesn't work for me?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you must combine tabularx and longtable, I prefer ltxtable to ltablex:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ltxtable} 
\begin{document}



\LTXtable{\textwidth}{t1.tex}


\end{document}
```

where `t1.tex` is

```
\begin{longtable}{@{}cX@{}}  
\toprule
\textbf{Column 1} & \textbf{Column 2} \\[6pt]
\midrule
\endhead
$R$ & 1This is an example sentence \\[6pt]
$R$ & 2As well as the line before \\[6pt]
$A$ & 3Also this is an example \\[6pt]
$R$ & 4This is an example sentence \\[6pt]
$R$ & 5As well as the line before \\[6pt]
$A$ & 6Also this is an example \\[6pt]
$R$ & 7This is an example sentence \\[6pt]
$R$ & 8As well as the line before \\[6pt]
$A$ & 9Also this is an example \\[6pt]
$R$ & 10This is an example sentence \\[6pt]
$R$ & 11As well as the line before \\[6pt]
$A$ & 12Also this is an example \\[6pt]
$R$ & 13This is an example sentence \\[6pt]
$R$ & 14As well as the line before \\[6pt]
$A$ & 15Also this is an example \\[6pt]
$R$ & 16This is an example sentence \\[6pt]
$R$ & 17As well as the line before \\[6pt]
$A$ & 18Also this is an example \\[6pt]
$R$ & 19This is an example sentence \\[6pt]
$R$ & 20As well as the line before \\[6pt]
$A$ & 21Also this is an example \\[6pt]
$R$ & 22This is an example sentence \\[6pt]
$R$ & 23As well as the line before \\[6pt]
$A$ & 24Also this is an example \\[6pt]
$R$ & 25This is an example sentence \\[6pt]
$R$ & 26As well as the line before \\[6pt]
$A$ & 27Also this is an example \\[6pt]
$R$ & 28This is an example sentence \\[6pt]
$R$ & 29As well as the line before \\[6pt]
$A$ & 30Also this is an example \\[6pt]
$R$ & 31This is an example sentence \\[6pt]
$R$ & 32As well as the line before \\[6pt]
$A$ & 33Also this is an example \\[6pt]
$R$ & 34This is an example sentence \\[6pt]
$R$ & 35As well as the line before \\[6pt]
$A$ & 36Also this is an example \\[6pt]
$R$ & 37This is an example sentence \\[6pt]
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}
```

Comment: But `ltablex` is in Tex Live and MiKTeX. I'm not saying your package isn't superior (I've never used either) but it does require manual installation.

Comment: @cfr I didn't install it manually, just picked it from texlive default install

Comment: How odd. I was just going by http://ctan.org/pkg/ltxtable in comparison with http://ctan.org/pkg/ltablex. I didn't check against my own installation (which does include it, as you say).

Comment: could you please expand on the preference of `ltxtable` over `ltablex`? The only difference I see is the first requiring a separate file but I fear I'm missing something such as they behaviour with labels or captions.

Comment: @carandraug well partly it's that I wrote that one, but ltablex redefines all tabularx whether or not they are intended to break over a page, which can have some side effects sometimes.

Answer (score 28):

With the correct code, it works fine. No `table` environment – a long table cannot possibly be a float, and the caption just after `begin{tabularx}`.

```
    \documentclass[11pt]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage{ltablex}

    \begin{document}

    \label{tab:daypack}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}cX@{}}
    \caption{Example of an table}\\
    \toprule
    \textbf{Column 1} & \textbf{Column 2} \\[6pt]
    \midrule
    \endhead

    $R$ & 1This is an example sentence \\[6pt]
    $R$ & 2As well as the line before \\[6pt]
    $A$ & 3Also this is an example \\[6pt]
    $R$ & 4This is an example sentence \\[6pt]
    $R$ & 5As well as the line before \\[6pt]
    $A$ & 6Also this is an example \\[6pt]
    $R$ & 7This is an example sentence \\[6pt]
    $R$ & 8As well as the line before \\[6pt]
    $A$ & 9Also this is an example \\[6pt]
    $R$ & 10This is an example sentence \\[6pt]
    $R$ & 11As well as the line before \\[6pt]
    $A$ & 12Also this is an example \\[6pt]
    $R$ & 13This is an example sentence \\[6pt]
    $R$ & 14As well as the line before \\[6pt]
    $A$ & 15Also this is an example \\[6pt]
    $R$ & 16This is an example sentence \\[6pt]
    $R$ & 17As well as the line before \\[6pt]
    $A$ & 18Also this is an example \\[6pt]
    $R$ & 19This is an example sentence \\[6pt]
    $R$ & 20As well as the line before \\[6pt]
    $A$ & 21Also this is an example \\[6pt]
    $R$ & 22This is an example sentence \\[6pt]
    $R$ & 23As well as the line before \\[6pt]
    $A$ & 24Also this is an example \\[6pt]
    $R$ & 25This is an example sentence \\[6pt]
    $R$ & 26As well as the line before \\[6pt]
    $A$ & 27Also this is an example \\[6pt]
    $R$ & 28This is an example sentence \\[6pt]
    $R$ & 29As well as the line before \\[6pt]
    $A$ & 30Also this is an example \\[6pt]
    $R$ & 31This is an example sentence \\[6pt]
    $R$ & 32As well as the line before \\[6pt]
    $A$ & 33Also this is an example \\[6pt]
    $R$ & 34This is an example sentence \\[6pt]
    $R$ & 35As well as the line before \\[6pt]
    $A$ & 36Also this is an example \\[6pt]
    $R$ & 37This is an example sentence \\[6pt]
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! :) the result looks perfect. However, I try and try but in the original document i get `! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.` Have you any idea why?

Comment: Impossible to say without seeing the code and the .log. Probably you inserted a `\\` or a blankline just after the end of an environment. Usually, the .log tells you where this happens.

Comment: Thank you very much. Somehow in `ltablex` seems to create trouble inside my template. Therefore I've chosen the proposal from David Carlisle. However, this solution works in an normal environment and is very elegant!

Comment: How could one force the table to break at an specific line, @Bernard? Thank you.

Comment: @Bernard That solution worked automagically

Comment: I've defined a new environment using `tabularx` as follows: `\newenvironment{tab}{\tabularx{\textwidth}{cXr}}{\endtabularx \vspace{\baselineskip}}`. Without the `ltablex` the file compiles fine, but with `ltablex` I get the error message `\begin{tab} on input line 42 ended by \end{tabularx}`. Any ideas?

Comment: FWIW, found the solution to my problem: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/417921/error-with-own-environment-using-ltablex?rq=1

Comment: @Bernard How do you get the table to extend to 100% in width?

Comment: 100% of  what? It is coded to use the whole line width.

Comment: This left aligns the tables in the entire document. Is there a way to center align the tables explicitly?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? The table has total width equal to text width, so it is *ipso facto* centred. Unless you've modified something in the code?

Comment: @kexxcream I needed `\keepXColumns` before the table to get the extension.

Comment: @filipos: This is set automatically with the more recent `xltabular` package (which loads `ltablex`).

Comment: This is a very nice and elegant solution. One issue I got is that the caption is not repeated on every page; it is displayed only on the top. I am using custom rows derived from `X`, do you think this could be the reason?

Comment: @mcy: If your table breaks over pages, you have to use `xltabular`, with the syntax of `longtable`, i.e.  `\caption` has to be used in the `\endfirsthead` section, and repeated in the `endhead` section. Also, I suppose you meant you're using custom *columns* derived from `X`?

Comment: @Bernard oh, right *columns* derived from `X`. That was an incorrect choice of word :). Thank you, I will try `xltabular` with `longtable` as you suggested. The example you showed in the answer uses `tabularx` and repeats caption as well as the header row without `xltabular` or `longtable`, though, just for curiosity how/why does it do that?

Comment: Not with longtable – just xltabular, which incorporates the functionalities of longtable to tabularx. For your question, I don't remember the details, but at the time I posted,  the `xltabular` package did not exist yet, and I used `ltablex`, which did a similar job, but was a bit more complex to use. Actually, `xltabular` loads `ltablex`.

Answer (score 5):

Use `longtable` of the package `longtable`

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ltablex} 
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{cc}  
\caption{Example of an table} \\
\textbf{Column 1} & \textbf{Column 2} \\[6pt]
$R$ & 1This is an example sentence \\[6pt]
$R$ & 2As well as the line before \\[6pt]
$A$ & 3Also this is an example \\[6pt]
$R$ & 4This is an example sentence \\[6pt]
$R$ & 5As well as the line before \\[6pt]
$A$ & 6Also this is an example \\[6pt]
$R$ & 7This is an example sentence \\[6pt]
$R$ & 8As well as the line before \\[6pt]
$A$ & 9Also this is an example \\[6pt]
$R$ & 10This is an example sentence \\[6pt]
$R$ & 11As well as the line before \\[6pt]
$A$ & 12Also this is an example \\[6pt]
$R$ & 13This is an example sentence \\[6pt]
$R$ & 14As well as the line before \\[6pt]
$A$ & 15Also this is an example \\[6pt]
$R$ & 16This is an example sentence \\[6pt]
$R$ & 17As well as the line before \\[6pt]
$A$ & 18Also this is an example \\[6pt]
$R$ & 19This is an example sentence \\[6pt]
$R$ & 20As well as the line before \\[6pt]
$A$ & 21Also this is an example \\[6pt]
$R$ & 22This is an example sentence \\[6pt]
$R$ & 23As well as the line before \\[6pt]
$A$ & 24Also this is an example \\[6pt]
$R$ & 25This is an example sentence \\[6pt]
$R$ & 26As well as the line before \\[6pt]
$A$ & 27Also this is an example \\[6pt]
$R$ & 28This is an example sentence \\[6pt]
$R$ & 29As well as the line before \\[6pt]
$A$ & 30Also this is an example \\[6pt]
$R$ & 31This is an example sentence \\[6pt]
$R$ & 32As well as the line before \\[6pt]
$A$ & 33Also this is an example \\[6pt]
$R$ & 34This is an example sentence \\[6pt]
$R$ & 35As well as the line before \\[6pt]
$A$ & 36Also this is an example \\[6pt]
$R$ & 37This is an example sentence \\[6pt]
\end{longtable}    

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This solution is very similar (aside of alignment) to David Carlisle. However it works fine and I rated it positively. Have a nice day!

Comment: We could extend possibilities of the longtable package by loading the tabu package, http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabu. Then we would use the `longtabu` environment instead of `longtable`.