# undefined control sequence: problem with \printbibliography

Tags: biblatex, errors

I have used `\cite` and `\footfullcitation`, now both in text and in footnote, they have been cited as the `bibtexkey` which I have chosen in Jabref.

It looks like(in footnote):

> 1 bibtexkey

It should look like (or something similar) (in footnote):

> 1 Author.bookname.publisher.pp.10-23

It looks like (in text):

> [bibtexkey]1

It should look like(in text):

> [1]

Question 2: And How can I reduce the space between the information in citation? Or how can I choose which information (author and bookname only,for example) I want to keep partial citation information in footnote but full citation in bibliography?

It looks like(in footnote):

> 1 author. (big space) articlename.     (big space)         [Accessed on 24.11.2016].    (big space)  Available on:www.google.com/...

It should look like:

> 1 Author.articlename.[Accessed on 24.11.2016].Available on:www.google.com/...

Question 3: TexMaker produces no bibliography in the end of my text, I have no idea why (these 3 questions come with my complete script.)

My shorten script is under (with the shorter script have the 2 following errors(which you might not regenerate, I have no idea why...):

```
! pdfTeX error (font expansion): auto expansion is only possible with scalable fonts. <to be read again> \endgroup \set@typeset@protect l.28 \end{document} 

! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,
            style=authoryear,
            natbib=true, 
            style=numeric-comp
            ]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{microtype}

    \usepackage{filecontents}
    \begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
      @book{ASH,
        author = {Seiffert, U. and Wech, L.},
        year = {2003},
        title = {Automotive Safety Handbook},
      }
    \end{filecontents*}
    \addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

    \begin{document}
    \blindtext \cite{ASH}

    \printbibliography

    \end{document}
```

Comment: do you get the stated error message from the code as posted? I do not even if I fix it to look for \jobname.bib rather than Bib.bib

Comment: i get a bibtex error `Illegal, another \bibstyle command---line 3 of file xxx.aux`

Comment: I do deleted many lines in order to shorten the script. I can update the post and post the complete version . @DavidCarlisle

Comment: Do not post a big file post the smallest file you can _that generates the error, Just keep deleting things and check at each stage that you still get the error (remove your .bbl file each time before trying)

Comment: Have you _tried_ the new file? it tries to input `Bib.bib` which isn't generated (unless the file is Bib.tex) it then generates the error  `! Undefined control sequence.
l.56     \blindtext` it does not generate the error in the question.

Comment: Thank you. It did help with deleting .bbl file. The error is disappeared, but still, I got no bibliography in the end of my text...

Comment: See my answer which shows how to fix the bibtex error and produce a bibliography as shown in the image.

Comment: This would also be an error: `\addbibresource{\Bib.bib}` (unless, perhaps, you have defined a command called `\Bib`).

Comment: @jon I have renamed my bibliography file. The error in my main post is gone, but latex produces no bibliography in the end of my text.

Comment: as jon says the line `\addbibresource{\Bib.bib}` will give an error abut `\Bib` not being defined and not input a bibliography. the file your code generates is `\jobname.bib` as I showed already in my answer.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes, you are right. I have changed to \jobname.bib, the error from my complete script is gone, but latex generates no bibliography in the end of my text. Should I open a new topic? because the citation in footnote is also not correct ...

Comment: please fix the example in the question then! also _remove_ every package in the question that is not needed to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: I have edited my question.Can you help to highlight the error parts and command part? @DavidCarlisle

Comment: sorry this still has the same bibtex error that I highlighted an hour ago in my answer `This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2016)
The top-level auxiliary file: xxx.aux
The style file: IEEEtran.bst
Illegal, another \bibstyle command---line 3 of file xxx.aux
 : \bibstyle` I can't help further.

Comment: If you use the `biblatex` package, you **cannot ever** use the command `\bibliographystyle`.

Comment: Thank you! But how can I then use "IEEEtran" style of citation? @jon

Comment: Well, you are in luck that you can do `\usepackage[style=ieee]{biblatex}` because someone has developed a style for `biblatex` that follows the patter of the official IEEEtran package. The command `\bibliographystyle` is for traditional BibTeX styles and packages such as `natbib`. `biblatex` has its own entire ecosystem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code posted produces a a bibtex error about duplicate style (not the tex error shown in the question) that can be fixed by commenting out the extra style specification:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[outdir=./]{epstopdf}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,
            style=authoryear,
            natbib=true, 
            style=numeric-comp
            ]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
  @book{ASH,
    author = {Seiffert, U. and Wech, L.},
    year = {2003},
    title = {Automotive Safety Handbook},
  }
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\blindtext \cite{ASH}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

processing this with pdflatex, bibtex, pdflatex pdflatex runs without error

[image]

Comment: 2 errors come with exactly your script (which obviously not your errors.): ! pdfTeX error (font expansion): auto expansion is only possible with scalable fonts. <to be read again> \endgroup \set@typeset@protect l.28 \end{document}   ! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

Comment: @Vivian you should not get that, the default setup should be using scalable fonts, but anyway just comment out the microtype package for now.