# Error with own environment using ltablex

Tags: tables, environments, ltablex

I am trying to get `ltablex` to work using the following code based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42331/):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\keepXColumns

\newenvironment{test}
    {%
     \tabularx{\textwidth}{lX}
    }
    {%
     \endtabularx
    }

\begin{document}

\begin{test}
    row 1 & \blindtext[2] \\
    row 2 & \blindtext \\
    row 3 & \blindtext[2] \\
\end{test}

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately the following error is thrown:

> ! LaTeX Error: \begin{test} on input line 16 ended by \end{tabularx}.
>
> See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation. Type  H
>     for immediate help.  ...
>
> l.20 \end{test}

How can I fix this to be able to get a table spanning multiple pages and the `X` column type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No idea why the test does not work (probably need @DavidCarlisle to explain it). Here is a working alternative using `environ`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{blindtext,environ}
\keepXColumns

% \newenvironment{test}
% {%
%   \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lX}
%     }
%     {%
%   \end{tabularx}
% }


\NewEnviron{test}{
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lX}
    \BODY
  \end{tabularx}
}



\begin{document}

\begin{test}
    row 1 & \blindtext[2] \\
    row 2 & \blindtext \\
    row 3 & \blindtext[2] \\
\end{test}

 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to reinsert the code that tabularx uses to test for such internal `\endtabularx`. It works for your example but I didn't try to really understand the code and so neither know if both patches are necessary (it works also only with the second) and if it breaks something else.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\keepXColumns
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\pretocmd\TX@endtabularx{%
     \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
     \TX@find@endtabularxa\csname end\TX@\endcsname
     \endtabularx\TX@\endtabularx\TX@find@endtabularxa
     }{}{\fail}

\patchcmd\TX@endtabularx{\end{tabularx}}{%
   \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
   \TX@find@endtabularxbb
    \expandafter\end\expandafter{\TX@}%
    \endtabularx\TX@\endtabularx\TX@find@endtabularxb
    }{}{\fail}

\makeatother     


\newenvironment{test}
    {%
     \tabularx{\textwidth}{lX}
    }
    {%
     \endtabularx
    }

\begin{document}

\begin{test}
    row 1 & \blindtext[2] \\
    row 2 & \blindtext \\
    row 3 & \blindtext[2] \\
\end{test}

\end{document}
```