# Tabularx table - break across page

Tags: page-breaking, tabularx

I have a table created using `tabularx` which is too big to fit onto one page. Is is possible to make it break across pages, whilst maintaining the current style?

I have tried to remove the `table` environment and keep the `tabularx`as suggested in this link [TEX link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165793/how-to-make-a-table-on-more-than-one-page-by-using-the-table-environment) but still have problems.

MWE:

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
\usepackage{caption}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{pdflscape,afterpage}

\begin{document}
    \begin{landscape}% Landscape page
\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Cognitive walkthrough goals, tasks and actions}
\label{table:comparison of techniques}
    \small
    \setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{
       >{\columncolor{red!30}} l
                          *{4}{X}
                            }
    \Xhline{1pt}
    \rowcolor{red!30}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}
    & \thead{Column 2} & \thead{Column 3}
    & \thead{Column 4} & \thead{Column 5}       \\
    \rowcolor{black}
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\textcolor{white}{Title 1}}  \\
Part 1
    &   To make your document look professionally produced, Word provides header, footer, cover page, and text box designs that complement each other. For example, you can add a matching cover page, header, and sidebar. Click Insert and then choose the elements you want from the different galleries.
        & To make your document look professionally produced, Word provides header, footer, cover page, and text box designs that complement each other. For example, you can add a matching cover page, header, and sidebar. Click Insert and then choose the elements you want from the different galleries.
            & To make your document look professionally produced, Word provides header, footer, cover page, and text box designs that complement each other. For example, you can add a matching cover page, header, and sidebar. Click Insert and then choose the elements you want from the different galleries.
                & To make your document look professionally produced, Word provides header, footer, cover page, and text box designs that complement each other. For example, you can add a matching cover page, header, and sidebar. Click Insert and then choose the elements you want from the different galleries.                      \\
    \Xhline{0.25pt}
Part 2
   &   To make your document look professionally produced, Word provides header, footer, cover page, and text box designs that complement each other. For example, you can add a matching cover page, header, and sidebar. Click Insert and then choose the elements you want from the different galleries.
        & To make your document look professionally produced, Word provides header, footer, cover page, and text box designs that complement each other. For example, you can add a matching cover page, header, and sidebar. Click Insert and then choose the elements you want from the different galleries.
            & To make your document look professionally produced, Word provides header, footer, cover page, and text box designs that complement each other. For example, you can add a matching cover page, header, and sidebar. Click Insert and then choose the elements you want from the different galleries.
                & To make your document look professionally produced, Word provides header, footer, cover page, and text box designs that complement each other. For example, you can add a matching cover page, header, and sidebar. Click Insert and then choose the elements you want from the different galleries.                      \\
    \rowcolor{black}
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\textcolor{white}{Title 2}}  \\
Part 3
    &   To make your document look professionally produced, Word provides header, footer, cover page, and text box designs that complement each other. For example, you can add a matching cover page, header, and sidebar. Click Insert and then choose the elements you want from the different galleries.
            & To make your document look professionally produced, Word provides header, footer, cover page, and text box designs that complement each other. For example, you can add a matching cover page, header, and sidebar. Click Insert and then choose the elements you want from the different galleries.
                & To make your document look professionally produced, Word provides header, footer, cover page, and text box designs that complement each other. For example, you can add a matching cover page, header, and sidebar. Click Insert and then choose the elements you want from the different galleries.
                    & To make your document look professionally produced, Word provides header, footer, cover page, and text box designs that complement each other. For example, you can add a matching cover page, header, and sidebar. Click Insert and then choose the elements you want from the different galleries.                      \\
        \rowcolor{black}
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\textcolor{white}{Title 3}}  \\
Part 1
    &   To make your document look professionally produced, Word provides header, footer, cover page, and text box designs that complement each other. For example, you can add a matching cover page, header, and sidebar. Click Insert and then choose the elements you want from the different galleries.
        & To make your document look professionally produced, Word provides header, footer, cover page, and text box designs that complement each other. For example, you can add a matching cover page, header, and sidebar. Click Insert and then choose the elements you want from the different galleries.
            & To make your document look professionally produced, Word provides header, footer, cover page, and text box designs that complement each other. For example, you can add a matching cover page, header, and sidebar. Click Insert and then choose the elements you want from the different galleries.
                & To make your document look professionally produced, Word provides header, footer, cover page, and text box designs that complement each other. For example, you can add a matching cover page, header, and sidebar. Click Insert and then choose the elements you want from the different galleries.                      \\
    \Xhline{0.25pt}
Part 2
    &   To make your document look professionally produced, Word provides header, footer, cover page, and text box designs that complement each other. For example, you can add a matching cover page, header, and sidebar. Click Insert and then choose the elements you want from the different galleries.
        & To make your document look professionally produced, Word provides header, footer, cover page, and text box designs that complement each other. For example, you can add a matching cover page, header, and sidebar. Click Insert and then choose the elements you want from the different galleries.
            & To make your document look professionally produced, Word provides header, footer, cover page, and text box designs that complement each other. For example, you can add a matching cover page, header, and sidebar. Click Insert and then choose the elements you want from the different galleries.
    & To make your document look professionally produced, Word provides header, footer, cover page, and text box designs that complement each other. For example, you can add a matching cover page, header, and sidebar. Click Insert and then choose the elements you want from the different galleries.                      \\
    \Xhline{0.25pt}
Part 3
    &   To make your document look professionally produced, Word provides header, footer, cover page, and text box designs that complement each other. For example, you can add a matching cover page, header, and sidebar. Click Insert and then choose the elements you want from the different galleries.
        & To make your document look professionally produced, Word provides header, footer, cover page, and text box designs that complement each other. For example, you can add a matching cover page, header, and sidebar. Click Insert and then choose the elements you want from the different galleries.
            & To make your document look professionally produced, Word provides header, footer, cover page, and text box designs that complement each other. For example, you can add a matching cover page, header, and sidebar. Click Insert and then choose the elements you want from the different galleries.
                & To make your document look professionally produced, Word provides header, footer, cover page, and text box designs that complement each other. For example, you can add a matching cover page, header, and sidebar. Click Insert and then choose the elements you want from the different galleries.                      \\
    \Xhline{1pt}
\end{tabularx}%
    \end{table}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Picture - current output
[image]

Grateful for any advice and thanks in advance!

Comment: It is possible with the `ltablex` package, but be aware it won't break the table  inside a row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a code with `ltablex`. Note the syntax, in particular for the caption, is the same as for `longtable` (`\endhead`, `\endfoot` and the like):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, ltablex}
\usepackage{caption}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries \cellcolor{red!30}}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{pdflscape,afterpage}

\begin{document}

    \begin{landscape}% Landscape page
    \small
    \setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{
       >{\columncolor{red!30}} l
                          *{3}{X}X@{}
                            }\caption{Cognitive walkthrough goals, tasks and actions}
\label{table:comparison of techniques}\\
  \Xhline{1pt}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor{red!30}}
    &\thead{Column 2} &\thead{Column 3}
    & \thead{Column 4} &\multicolumn{1}{>{\columncolor{red!30}[6pt][0pt]\bfseries}c@{}}{\Centerstack{Column 5\\Lalala}} \\
    \Xhline{0.25pt}
 \endfirsthead
  \Xhline{1pt}
% \rowcolor{red!30}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor{red!30}}
    &\thead{Column 2} &\thead{Column 3}
    & \thead{Column 4} &\multicolumn{1}{>{\columncolor{red!30}[6pt][0pt]\bfseries}c@{}}{\Centerstack{Column 5\\Lalala}} \\
    \Xhline{0.25pt}
 \endhead
 \Xhline{0.25pt}
 \endfoot
 \Xhline{1pt}
 \endlastfoot
    \rowcolor{black}
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\textcolor{white}{\bfseries Title 1}} \\
Part 1
    & To make your document look professionally produced, Word provides header, footer, cover page, and text box designs that complement each other. For example, you can add a matching cover page, header, and sidebar. Click Insert and then choose the elements you want from the different galleries.
        & To make your document look professionally produced, Word provides header, footer, cover page, and text box designs that complement each other. For example, you can add a matching cover page, header, and sidebar. Click Insert and then choose the elements you want from the different galleries.
            & To make your document look professionally produced, Word provides header, footer, cover page, and text box designs that complement each other. For example, you can add a matching cover page, header, and sidebar. Click Insert and then choose the elements you want from the different galleries.
                & To make your document look professionally produced, Word provides header, footer, cover page, and text box designs that complement each other. For example, you can add a matching cover page, header, and sidebar. Click Insert and then choose the elements you want from the different galleries. \\
    \Xhline{0.25pt}
Part 2
   & To make your document look professionally produced, Word provides header, footer, cover page, and text box designs that complement each other. For example, you can add a matching cover page, header, and sidebar. Click Insert and then choose the elements you want from the different galleries.
        & To make your document look professionally produced, Word provides header, footer, cover page, and text box designs that complement each other. For example, you can add a matching cover page, header, and sidebar. Click Insert and then choose the elements you want from the different galleries.
            & To make your document look professionally produced, Word provides header, footer, cover page, and text box designs that complement each other. For example, you can add a matching cover page, header, and sidebar. Click Insert and then choose the elements you want from the different galleries.
                & To make your document look professionally produced, Word provides header, footer, cover page, and text box designs that complement each other. For example, you can add a matching cover page, header, and sidebar. Click Insert and then choose the elements you want from the different galleries. \\
    \rowcolor{black}
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\textcolor{white}{\bfseries Title 2}} \\*
Part 3
    & To make your document look professionally pro\bfseries duced, Word provides header, footer, cover page, and text box designs that complement each other. For example, you can add a matching cover page, header, and sidebar. Click Insert and then choose the elements you want from the different galleries.
            & To make your document look professionally produced, Word provides header, footer, cover page, and text box designs that complement each other. For example, you can add a matching cover page, header, and sidebar. Click Insert and then choose the elements you want from the different galleries.
                & To make your document look professionally produced, Word provides header, footer, cover page, and text box designs that complement each other. For example, you can add a matching cover page, header, and sidebar. Click Insert and then choose the elements you want from the different galleries.
                    & To make your document look professionally produced, Word provides header, footer, cover page, and text box designs that complement each other. For example, you can add a matching cover page, header, and sidebar. Click Insert and then choose the elements you want from the different galleries. \\
        \rowcolor{black}
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\textcolor{white}{\bfseries Title 3}} \\
Part 1
    & To make your document look professionally produced, Word provides header, footer, cover page, and text box designs that complement each other. For example, you can add a matching cover page, header, and sidebar. Click Insert and then choose the elements you want from the different galleries.
        & To make your document look professionally produced, Word provides header, footer, cover page, and text box designs that complement each other. For example, you can add a matching cover page, header, and sidebar. Click Insert and then choose the elements you want from the different galleries.
            & To make your document look professionally produced, Word provides header, footer, cover page, and text box designs that complement each other. For example, you can add a matching cover page, header, and sidebar. Click Insert and then choose the elements you want from the different galleries.
                & To make your document look professionally produced, Word provides header, footer, cover page, and text box designs that complement each other. For example, you can add a matching cover page, header, and sidebar. Click Insert and then choose the elements you want from the different galleries. \\
    \Xhline{0.25pt}
Part 2
    & To make your document look professionally produced, Word provides header, footer, cover page, and text box designs that complement each other. For example, you can add a matching cover page, header, and sidebar. Click Insert and then choose the elements you want from the different galleries.
        & To make your document look professionally produced, Word provides header, footer, cover page, and text box designs that complement each other. For example, you can add a matching cover page, header, and sidebar. Click Insert and then choose the elements you want from the different galleries.
            & To make your document look professionally produced, Word provides header, footer, cover page, and text box designs that complement each other. For example, you can add a matching cover page, header, and sidebar. Click Insert and then choose the elements you want from the different galleries.
    & To make your document look professionally produced, Word provides header, footer, cover page, and text box designs that complement each other. For example, you can add a matching cover page, header, and sidebar. Click Insert and then choose the elements you want from the different galleries. \\
    \Xhline{0.25pt}
Part 3
    & To make your document look professionally produced, Word provides header, footer, cover page, and text box designs that complement each other. For example, you can add a matching cover page, header, and sidebar. Click Insert and then choose the elements you want from the different galleries.
        & To make your document look professionally produced, Word provides header, footer, cover page, and text box designs that complement each other. For example, you can add a matching cover page, header, and sidebar. Click Insert and then choose the elements you want from the different galleries.
            & To make your document look professionally produced, Word provides header, footer, cover page, and text box designs that complement each other. For example, you can add a matching cover page, header, and sidebar. Click Insert and then choose the elements you want from the different galleries.
                & To make your document look professionally produced, Word provides header, footer, cover page, and text box designs that complement each other. For example, you can add a matching cover page, header, and sidebar. Click Insert and then choose the elements you want from the different galleries.
\end{tabularx}%
% \end{table}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you, the code works perfectly! I have one follow-up query. Is it possible to wrap the text in 'Column 2,3 etc...'? If so, can you direct me to the part of the code which I need to alter?

Comment: @Kevin: I'm n't sure to understand fully what you'd like. Do you mean wrap the text in the cells with Column 2, &c. (these marked with `\thead`)? In the other cells, as we have `X` columns, that is automatic.

Comment: Yes, when I add text to the other cells, it is wrapped nicely (as per your output image). However, if I replace the words 'Column 2' with 'Is the effect of the current action the same as the user's goals' I lose the text wrapping. I am not sure if this is due to the text exceeding column width or the text wrap feature has been lost (the `\thead` does not seem to work). If you can advise to what I need to change that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: No it's normal: you have  to make line breaks by hand (`makecell`is for use with  standard cells, where normally there can be no line break). Other solution: let the cell normal (`X` type), but add `\bfseries`.

Comment: Thanks! Adding `bfseries` works for Columns 2-4 but Column 5 is part of a `multicolumn`. I amended the code to`\multicolumn{1}{>{\columncolor{red!30}[6pt][0pt]}c@{}}\bfseries{Will the user understand the feedback?}` but this disrupts the the cells directly below it. Have I missed a key step?

Comment: No, it's fine. B.t.w. , Column 5 is not a in `\thead` line the others for colour overflowing outside the table reasons (I've set the last `\tabcolsep` to 0 in the table preamble).

Comment: Ok. But how do I wrap the text in Column 5? Are you able to paste an example code please?

Comment: @Kevin: I've updated my code for that. Unforfotunately we can't use a `\multicolumn{\thead}` in the last column, as `makecell has some problems with colouring cells, so I replaced it with `\Centerstack` from `stackengine`. Please see the updated answer, if it's OK.

Comment: many thanks for the updated answer. Unfortunately the problem is unchanged. `Centerstack` disrupts the cells directly below it. If you replace the text 'Column 5 Lalala' with 'Will the user understand the feedback?', then you will see that the text in the cells below take up half the cell width.

Comment: @Kevin: I have no such problem (manually inserting line breaks, of course). Did you compile twice?

Comment: I was missing the manual line breaks. The code works perfectly now. Thank you so much!